Build Failure in Flutter Project When Adding GetStream Package: Gradle Dependency Conflict
I am experiencing a build failure in my Flutter project when I add the GetStream package to the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file. The build process takes several minutes and eventually throws an error related to the flutter_webrtc package's Gradle build file. The error does not occur when the GetStream package is removed.
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading packages...
_flutterfire_internals 1.3.35 (1.3.37 available)
collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
firebase_core 2.32.0 (3.1.0 available)
firebase_messaging 14.9.4 (15.0.1 available)
firebase_messaging_platform_interface 4.5.37 (4.5.39 available)
firebase_messaging_web 3.8.7 (3.8.9 available)
flutter_lints 3.0.2 (4.0.0 available)
flutter_webrtc 0.10.8 (0.11.1 available)
http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
lints 3.0.0 (4.0.0 available)
material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
rxdart 0.27.7 (0.28.0 available)
test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.2 available)
vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.4 available)
web_socket_channel 2.4.5 (3.0.0 available)
Got dependencies!
18 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try flutter pub outdated for more information.
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file '/Users/FarukBaba/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_webrtc-0.10.8/android/build.gradle' line: 67
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_webrtc'.
Could not find method io.github.webrtc-sdk:android:114.5735.10() for arguments [build_9w9wbumh15jbh32v2x0hddv0l$_run_closure5$_closure13@8351a1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I ensure that I am using the latest package of the getstream. which I also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
I created a new Flutter project and added only the getstream package and the issue persisted.
